# gRPC calls on ActiveMQ?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, grpc

I am working with ActiveMQ. I want to put gRPC calls as a message on ActiveMQ. As soon as consumer picks a message the gRPC in the message should execute.

gRPC calls take parameters so I want to understand how to send these parameters in the message body along with the method name/identifier. Is there any another way of achieving this which is followed already?

Example:

```
someResponse response = someStub.rpcMethodName(parameter); // grpc call
```

What I need is to store this statement in some format on ActiveMQ without calling the gRPC now. Then in the future when the consumer of ActiveMQ picks up the message containing this statement it should execute this gRPC call.

Comment: @JustinBertram , changed the ques desc plz check.Thanks

Comment: I was just curious how often does we come across cases where we put gRPC calls on queue or if it is a rare occurence . Anyway that was not the main ques.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am trying to store the rpc call on the message (gRPC call should not be executed right now) so that when the consumer picks up the message(from Activemq) in the future then it could use this info to recreate the rpc call can and execute it .
So either of storing the actual stub on the message or information required to recreate the stub will work. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Justin , so we can use XML , JSON,ProtoBuf to store the info required to recreate the gRPC call.Ok , got it.
Could you point me towards some examples of the same ? That would be really helpful .
Thank You

Comment: You should probably decide *which* solution you want to pursue and then open a new question about that.

Comment: Sure. Kindly confirm that I am understanding you correctly(above comment)
Thanks.

Comment: This-

''we can use XML , JSON,ProtoBuf to store the info required to recreate the gRPC call.''

Comment: I can confirm that your statement is accurate. That's a good summary of my answer.

Comment: @JustinBertram, asked another ques as you said .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67569136/pass-grpc-stub-over-activemq
Thank You.

Comment: When I told you to ask a new question it was in response to you asking for specific examples. I meant that you should decide on which format you would use to store the gRPC data (e.g. XML, JSON, ProtoBuf, etc.) and then ask for examples of *that*. Your new question is basically just a duplicate of this one and is likely to be closed.

Comment: @JustinBertram , check now . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure the gRPC call data in your message any way you want. You could use XML, JSON, ProtoBuf, etc. It's really up to however you want to do it. If all you really need are simple key/value pairs then you could just use JMS message properties to store the data you need.

I don't think using gRPC is particularly common, but it *is* common to use messages as a kind of "unit of work" to work with all kinds of remote resources (e.g. databases, REST services, microservices, etc.).

In any event, I would strongly recommend *against* using JMS `ObjectMessage`. `ObjectMessage` objects depend on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal their object payload. This process is not only slow but generally considered unsafe because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this. There are a number of other issues with using JMS `ObjectMessage` not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/) as well.